# When a user logs into a Windows AD environment, which attribute is looked up?

Tags: active-directory

When a user logs in to a Windows Active Directory environment, his/her password is validated against an AD server.  My question is what attribute is matched to the login name?  Is it userPrincipalName or is it uid or something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Jakob gave me the clue, I googled SAMAccountName and that lead me to userPrincipalName.  It seems that samAccountName is for Windows 2K and legacy systems.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679635%28v=vs.85%29.aspx for the details.